# MySQL join between dates that are not equal

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I want to join between two tables by dates.
the first table has date for each day - Table a.
The second table has few dates (not a date for each day) - Table b.
I want to be able to join the two tables in a way that
a.date=(the maximal date that is small or equal to a.date)

Is there a way to do that via MySQL?

Comment: Consider posting up DDLS and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1f14/2/0) for a possible solution:

```
SELECT A.Date AS ADate, A.Value AS AValue, 
(
 SELECT B.Date 
   FROM B 
   WHERE B.Date <= A.Date 
   ORDER BY B.Date DESC 
   LIMIT 1
) AS BDate,
(
 SELECT B.Value
   FROM B 
   WHERE B.Date <= A.Date 
   ORDER BY B.Date DESC 
   LIMIT 1
) AS BValue
FROM A 
WHERE A.Date = '2013-03-01'
```

In the above I am just using sub queries to pull the fields from table `B`.

Comment: But if a.date >b.date , the "on" won't be equal